# problem with console command, the content can not print anything?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and I wrote a very simple program to display something using console command like this

```js
function dogYears(dogName, age) {
  var years = age * 7;
  console.log(dogName + " is " + years + " years old");
}
var myDog = "Fido";
dogYears(myDog, 4);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercise2</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I hope that I made the function and then, use var to assigned the value myDog to Fido, and then I want to use the function dogYears to print by the command console.log.

But when I ran the file .html (I saved it by .html), it did not display anything.

What error did I get in this case ? Could you please help me in this one ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the appropriate log levels in your console? Look at the filter settings.

Comment: Your code is ok, but you need to show the console to see your message. Try with Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 then go to the Console tab

Comment: Hi, I edited your question and add the code to stackoverflow's snippet. As you can see it works ok. The `console.log` is not showing anything on web page, it shows it in the console (weird ah?). To do it you can click F12 and watch the console

Answer (score 1):

To display your result in browser's console just add your JavaScript logic inside script tag in your html file before closing body tag or create separate JavaScript file and import it using script tag

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercise2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function dogYears(dogName, age) {
    var years = age * 7;
    console.log(dogName + " is " + years + " years old");
  }
  var myDog = "Fido";
  dogYears(myDog, 4);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not viewing the console. The console is not on the webpage, but instead on a separate tab. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on the keyboard, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and then click on the console. There is nothing wrong with the code. But if you want a more protected function, you can use this JavaScript code.

```html
<script>
function dogYears(dogName, age) {
if(typeof(dogName)==="string"&&typeof(age)==="number"){
    var years = age * 7;
    console.log(dogName + " is " + years.toString() + " years old");
}else{
    console.log("Error you want to display");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display information on the browser, typed document.write instead of console.log

```html
<script>
    function dogYears(dogName, age) {
        var years = age * 7;
        document.write(dogName + " is " + years + " years old");
    }
     var myDog = "Fido";
     dogYears(myDog, 4);
</script>
```